# How can I reference page elements from an external class in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have several pages in my Xamarin.Forms app that require similar functionality, so I decided to make an external utility class that I can reference in all of them to reduce redundant code.

The code for one of the pages is:

```cs
public partial class Incontrol_page : TabbedPage
    {
        public Incontrol_page()
        {
            Boolean initialrun = true;
            Alert_Generator generator = new Alert_Generator();
            InitializeComponent();
            Task.Run(() => 
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    //code not relevant to the question removed here
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
                    {
                        List<Frame> offline_alerts = generator.GenAlerts("incontrol_offline", active_offline_events);
                        List<Frame> bandwidth_alerts = generator.GenAlerts("incontrol_bandwidth", active_bandwidth_events);
                        offline_stack.Children.Clear();
                        bandwidth_stack.Children.Clear();
                        foreach(Frame frame in offline_alerts)
                        {
                            offline_stack.Children.Add(frame);
                        }
                        foreach(Frame frame in bandwidth_alerts)
                        {
                            bandwidth_stack.Children.Add(frame);
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.Sleep(10000);
                }
            });
        }
        
    }
```

Essentially the method pulls data from an API and creates a list of frames that differ slightly depending on the kind of data pulled. This part works fine, however I run into functionality problems in the frames themselves. Here is a sample of the code used to make the frames:

```cs
public List<Frame> GenAlerts(string type, List<String> active_events)
        {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                //irrelevant code removed

                foreach (var obj in list)
                {
                    //irrelevant code removed
                    Frame alert_frame = new Frame
                    {
                        //irrelevant code removed
                        Content = new StackLayout
                        {
                            //irrelevant code removed
                            Children =
                            {
                                Orientation=Xamarin.Forms.StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                                Children =
                                {
                                    GetChildren(obj,color,wc,type)[0],
                                    GetChildren(obj,color,wc,type)[1]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    return_list.Add(alert_frame);
                }
                return return_list;
            }
        }
public List<View> GetChildren(Alert obj, Color color, WebClient wc, string type)
        {
            //creates info button with popup for the event readout
            Button info = new Button()
            {
                //attributes here
            };
            info.Clicked += async (sender, args) => await DisplayAlert("Event Info", obj.Change, "Okay");

            //creates delete button that deletes the parent alert object from the stack layout and sends the command to the api to remove it from the SQL table
            Button delete = new Button()
            {
                //attributes here
            };
            delete.Clicked += async (sender, args) => await Remove(obj, wc, type);

            List<View> alert_frames = new List<View>();

            alert_frames.Add(info);
            alert_frames.Add(delete);

            return alert_frames;
        }

async Task Remove(Alert obj, WebClient wc, string type)
        {
            View frame = new Frame();
            foreach (Frame element in alert_stack.Children)
            {
                if (element.StyleId == obj.EventKey)
                {
                    frame = element;
                }
            }
            alert_stack.Children.Remove(frame);
            //sends the remove command for the event's id to the api
            var jsonstr = wc.DownloadString("http://172.30.211.33:5000/remove?db="+type+"&id=" + obj.EventKey);
        }
```

The big problems for me come in the Remove(Alert obj, WebClient wc, string type) task. In a previous implementation when all this was directly in the code behind for each page instead of in a reusable method I was able to simply get the reference for the parent frame and remove the desired element at the press of a button but it isn't that easy from an external method not directly attached to the page. Is it possible for me to pass the reference to alert_stack as an argument of GenAlerts()?

In the same vein, I am not sure how I can make the DisplayAlert() function call actually work from the external method. Is there a way I can get some reference to the parent page calling the function to allow this to actually display an alert on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible for me to pass the reference to alert_stack as an
> argument of GenAlerts()?

Yes.  Have you tried?  It should be as simple as

```
List<Frame> offline_alerts = generator.GenAlerts(offline_stack, "incontrol_offline", active_offline_events);
```

and

```
public List<Frame> GenAlerts(StackLayout parent, string type, List<String> active_events)
```

> Is there a way I can get some reference to the parent page

Yes.  You could either pass in an explicit reference to the current page, or do this

```
App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(...);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved both of my issues perfectly :)